# Windows 2012 R2 Builtin/Remote desktop users AD group not working

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

[Windows Server 2012 Remote Desktop Users AD Group Not Working](https://serverfault.com/questions/849782/windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-users-ad-group-not-working)

Hi I have a query on the answer given for the question in the above link

I have added users to builtin "Remote Desktop Users" in Active directory. But the users are not able to login remotely to neither DC's nor any Member servers.

1)How can i give the "SeNetworkLogonRight" to domain users without giving Administrative privileges,it
can be only given through GPO?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that they are also in the Remote Desktop Users group on ALL member and DC machines.

you can do this by going into:

Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment/Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services.

and then adding the users/groups that you are trying to RDP into the machines.

Comment: Thank you for that point